# Error: Failure while executing; `cp -pR /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/. /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates` exited with 1

Tags: python, homebrew

When i install python by brew, it shows error:

```
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: Permission denied
cp: utimensat: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/.: Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing; `cp -pR /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/. /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates` exited with 1. Here's the output:
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew/ca-certificates.rb: No such file or directory
cp: utimensat: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem: No such file or directory
cp: utimensat: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: utimensat: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11/share: No such file or directory
cp: utimensat: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20221129-9397-882a6m/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11: Permission denied
cp: utimensat: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/.: Permission denied
```

HOW can i fix it and install python with brew? Before that, i was installed node and yarn with brew. I have tried uninstalling it and re-installing brew, but it doesn't work.
Thank you!

Comment: I faced the same issue this morning. Watching for response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it the following way:

I saw that the upgrade script tried to copy files from
`/private/tmp/d20221130-21318-e53mkn/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11` to `/usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-10-11` and I got a `Permission denied` meaning - I (the current mac user) could not edit/create files there.

So i went to `/usr/local/Cellar/` and saw that my user was not the owner of the folder `ca-certificates` and several others. So i just changed the onwer like this:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/

sudo chown -R REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME:admin *
```

And this fix the issue for me. A simple `brew upgrde` upgraded all my packages after that.

Hope this helps !